# Using the "Prolog in Scala" to find available type class instances

Tags: scala, shapeless, constraint-programming, logic-programming, type-level-computation

Considering https://speakerdeck.com/folone/theres-a-prolog-in-your-scala, I would like to "abuse" the Scala type system to find all instances of e.g. `CanBuildFrom` that match a given criteria. Prolog style, I would evaluate something in the lines of the following pseudocode:

```
can_build_from(Src, int, list[int])
Src = somecollectiontype1[int]
Src = somecollectiontype2[int]
... etc
```

i.e. the runtime would look up all the values for `Src` that satisfy the statement `can_build_from(Src, int, list[int])`.

Now, I'm aware that the primitive constraint/logic programming environment, which the Scala implicit lookup system is, isn't meant to be used for such tricks and is not able to "return" more than one found value for `Src` out of the box, so my question is: is there a "magic trick" to make it work so that somehow I'd get all the possible values for `X` in `CanBuildFrom[X, Int, List[Int]]`?

**Additional example:**

```
trait CanFoo[T, U]

implicit val canFooIntString  = new CanFoo[Int,     String] {}
implicit val canFooDblString  = new CanFoo[Double,  String] {}
implicit val canFooBoolString = new CanFoo[Boolean, String] {}
implicit val canFooIntSym     = new CanFoo[Int,     Symbol] {}
implicit val canFooDblSym     = new CanFoo[Double,  Symbol] {}
implicit val canFooBoolSym    = new CanFoo[Boolean, Symbol] {}
```

now I'd like to query `CanFoo[X, String]` and get back `X ∈ [Int, Double, Boolean]`, or `CanFoo[Int, X]` and get back `X ∈ [String, Symbol]`.

Alternatively, `CanFoo[X, String]` would return `List(canFooIntString, canFooDblString, canFooBoolString)`, i.e. all instances of `CanFoo` that match.

Comment: In this case the set is infinite: `X` can be `List[T]` for all `T` ... I suspect that not really what you were after.

Comment: @MilesSabin: even if with `List[Int]` as the output collection? maybe I don't understand CanBuildFrom then, but can the idea be made to work in general?

Comment: I'm not clear on what the general idea actually is ... could you give a few more examples?

Comment: @MilesSabin: I've added a simpler example.

Comment: OK, now suppose you had a low priority `def canFooDefaultUnit[T] = new CanFoo[T, Unit] {}` ... what would you expect the set for the first type argument to be?

Comment: If the query is `CanFoo[X, Unit]` you mean? I think I see your point but does this mean it's impossible, or at least generally impossible?

Comment: You tell me! What do you expect `CanFoo[X, Unit]` to yield?

Comment: ...perhaps an indication that `X` can be anything? If it's possible to encode somehow.

Comment: @ErikAllik Just out of interest: what are you planning to create? Apart from being interested, there might be another solution.

Comment: @EECOLOR: Actually I was literally trying to find which instances are available for the `CanBuildFrom` type class.

Comment: @ErikAllik Oh, haha, did not expect that. For that I can recommend something very ancient: the search option. It's available on most IDE's but also on a lot of websites. Jokes aside, it's still an interesting question though. I think it can however not be done without listing all possible candidates (all types available in the standard library).

Answer (score 2):

This can be done (at least in some cases) with compiler internals

```scala
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.internal.util
import scala.reflect.macros.{blackbox, contexts}

object Macros {

  def allImplicits[A]: List[String] = macro impl[A]

  def impl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._

    val context = c.asInstanceOf[contexts.Context]
    val global: context.universe.type = context.universe
    val analyzer: global.analyzer.type = global.analyzer
    val callsiteContext = context.callsiteTyper.context

    val tpA = weakTypeOf[A]

    val search = new analyzer.ImplicitSearch(
      tree = EmptyTree.asInstanceOf[global.Tree],
      pt = tpA.asInstanceOf[global.Type],
      isView = false,
      context0 = callsiteContext.makeImplicit(reportAmbiguousErrors = false),
      pos0 = c.enclosingPosition.asInstanceOf[util.Position]
    )

    q"${search.allImplicits.map(_.tree.symbol.toString).distinct}"
  }
}
```

```scala
allImplicits[CanFoo[_, String]]
// List(value canFooBoolString, value canFooDblString, value canFooIntString)
```

Tested in 2.13.0.

---

Still working in 2.13.10.

Scala 3 implementation is similar

```scala
import dotty.tools.dotc.typer.{Implicits => dottyImplicits}
import scala.quoted.{Expr, Quotes, Type, quotes}

inline def allImplicits[A]: List[String] = ${impl[A]}

def impl[A: Type](using Quotes): Expr[List[String]] = {
  import quotes.reflect.*
  given c: dotty.tools.dotc.core.Contexts.Context =
    quotes.asInstanceOf[scala.quoted.runtime.impl.QuotesImpl].ctx

  val typer = c.typer

  val search = new typer.ImplicitSearch(
    TypeRepr.of[A].asInstanceOf[dotty.tools.dotc.core.Types.Type],
    dotty.tools.dotc.ast.tpd.EmptyTree,
    Position.ofMacroExpansion.asInstanceOf[dotty.tools.dotc.util.SourcePosition].span
  )

  def eligible(contextual: Boolean): List[dottyImplicits.Candidate] =
    if contextual then
      if c.gadt.isNarrowing then
        dotty.tools.dotc.core.Contexts.withoutMode(dotty.tools.dotc.core.Mode.ImplicitsEnabled) {
          c.implicits.uncachedEligible(search.wildProto)
        }
      else c.implicits.eligible(search.wildProto)
    else search.implicitScope(search.wildProto).eligible


  def implicits(contextual: Boolean): List[dottyImplicits.SearchResult] =
    eligible(contextual).map(search.tryImplicit(_, contextual))

  val contextualImplicits = implicits(true)
  val nonContextualImplicits = implicits(false)
  val contextualSymbols = contextualImplicits.map(_.tree.symbol)
  val filteredNonContextual = nonContextualImplicits.filterNot(sr => contextualSymbols.contains(sr.tree.symbol))

  val implicitStrs = (contextualImplicits ++ filteredNonContextual).collect {
    case success: dottyImplicits.SearchSuccess => success.tree.asInstanceOf[ImplicitSearchSuccess].tree.show
  }

  Expr(implicitStrs)
}
```

```scala
trait CanFoo[T, U]

object CanFoo {
  given canFooIntString: CanFoo[Int, String] with {}
  given canFooDblString: CanFoo[Double, String] with {}
  given canFooBoolString: CanFoo[Boolean, String] with {}
  given canFooIntSym: CanFoo[Int, Symbol] with {}
  given canFooDblSym: CanFoo[Double, Symbol] with {}
  given canFooBoolSym: CanFoo[Boolean, Symbol] with {}
}

allImplicits[CanFoo[_, String]] 
//"CanFoo.canFooIntString", "CanFoo.canFooBoolString", "CanFoo.canFooDblString"
```

Scala 3.2.0.