# Scala: what can code in Context.eval reference?

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros, quill.io

It seems that the input of `Context.eval` can reference only values from different compilation unit:

```
// project 1
object Z {

  val foo = "WOOF"

  def impl(c: Context)(x: c.Expr[String]) = {
    val x1 = c.Expr[String](c.untypecheck(x.tree.duplicate))
    println(s"compile-time value is: ${c.eval(x1)}")
    x
  }
  def test(x: String) = macro impl
}

// project 2
object Y {
  val foo = "GOOF"
  val boo = Z.test(Z.foo)
}


println(Y.boo)
```

prints out `"WOOF"`, but if I replace boo with `val boo = Z.test(Y.foo)`, I get the following compilation error:

```
Error:(32, 29) exception during macro expansion:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Y$
at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.findClass(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:72)
...
```

Is there any way around this problem? I know that the queries defined with quill.io can reference methods from the same scope, but I wasn't able to find the trick they use to allow it.

Answer (score 5):

`Context#eval` can't evaluate runtime values. It's written in its scaladoc: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/reflect/scala/reflect/macros/Evals.scala#L61-L67

Let's modify your macro

```
def impl(c: blackbox.Context)(x: c.Expr[String]): c.Expr[String] = {
  import c.universe._
  println(s"input: ${showRaw(x.tree)}") // added
  val x1 = c.Expr[String](c.untypecheck(x.tree.duplicate))
  println(s"compile-time value is: ${c.eval(x1)}")
  x
}
```

Then we'll have

```
object App {
  /*class*/ object Y {
    val foo = "GOOF"

    val boo = Z.test(Z.foo)//Warning:scalac: input: Select(Select(Ident(Macros), Macros.Z), TermName("foo"))
                           //Warning:scalac: compile-time value is: WOOF
//  val boo1 = Z.test(Y.foo)//Warning:scalac: input: Select(Select(This(TypeName("App")), App.Y), TermName("foo"))
                            //Error: exception during macro expansion:  
                            //  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: App$Y$
//  val boo2 = Z.test((new Y).foo)//Warning:scalac: input: Select(Apply(Select(New(Select(This(TypeName("App")), App.Y)), termNames.CONSTRUCTOR), List()), TermName("foo"))
                                  //Error: exception during macro expansion: 
                                  //  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: App$Y
//  val boo3 = Z.test(foo) //Warning:scalac: input: Select(This(TypeName("Y")), TermName("foo"))
                           //Error: exception during macro expansion:
                           //  scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxError: reflective compilation has failed:
                           //    Internal error: unable to find the outer accessor symbol of object __wrapper$1$fd3cb1297ce8421e809ee5e821c2f708
                     // or
                           //Error: exception during macro expansion:  
                           //  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: App$Y$
    val boo4 = Z.test("abc")//Warning:scalac: input: Literal(Constant("abc"))
                            //Warning:scalac: compile-time value is: abc
    val boo5 = Z.test("abc" + "DEF")//Warning:scalac: input: Literal(Constant("abcDEF"))
                                    //Warning:scalac: compile-time value is: abcDEF
  }
}
```

Tree `This` means that it represents a runtime value. Just `ClassNotFoundException` sometimes happens faster than `ToolBoxError`. You subproject with macros `project 1` doesn't depend on subproject `project 2` so during compilation of macros `Y` is not found.

Difference between `Z.foo` and `foo` (aka `Y.foo`) is that `foo` is actually `this.foo` (compiler doesn't care here if `Y` is a class or object) and can be overriden in subclasses.

Quill doesn't use `eval`. It parses a tree into its own [AST](https://github.com/getquill/quill/blob/master/quill-core/src/main/scala/io/getquill/ast/Ast.scala) if it can or leave [`Dynamic`](https://github.com/getquill/quill/blob/master/quill-core/src/main/scala/io/getquill/ast/Ast.scala#L172) if it can't (i.e. if the tree corresponds to runtime value). And then it works with these two case differently: either during macros expansion with `QueryMeta` or during compile time + runtime with `Decoder`

https://github.com/getquill/quill/blob/master/quill-core/src/main/scala/io/getquill/context/QueryMacro.scala#L34-L38

So the workaround is **to work with runtime values at runtime.**

```
def impl(c: blackbox.Context)(x: c.Expr[String]): c.Expr[String] = {
  import c.universe._
  println(s"input: ${showRaw(x.tree)}")
  try {
    val x1 = c.Expr[String](c.untypecheck(x.tree.duplicate))
    val x2 = c.eval(x1)
    println(s"compile-time value is: $x2")
    c.Expr[String](q"$x2")
  } catch {
    case ex: Throwable =>
      println(ex.getMessage)
      x
  }
}
```

This is similar to https://github.com/getquill/quill/blob/master/quill-core/src/main/scala/io/getquill/context/ContextMacro.scala#L66-L68