# Def Macro, pass parameter from a value

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I have a working macros ie:

```
object Main extends App {

  println("Testing assert macro...")
  val result = Asserts.assert(false, "abc")

}
```

and

```
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox.Context
import scala.language.experimental.macros

object Asserts {
  val assertionsEnabled: Boolean = true

  def assert(cond: Boolean, msg: String): Unit = macro assertImpl

  def assertImpl(c: Context)(cond: c.Expr[Boolean], msg: c.Expr[String]) : c.Expr[Unit] = {
    import c.universe._
    cond.tree match {
      case Literal(Constant(cond: Boolean)) =>
        if (!cond) c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "Fix the code, whatever.") else c.Expr(q"()")
    }
  }
}
```

but question is:
how can I make this working ?:

```
  val cond: Boolean = false
  val result = Asserts.assert(cond, "abc")
```

now I have an error:

> Error:(8, 30) exception during macro expansion:  scala.MatchError:
> Main.this.cond (of class scala.reflect.internal.Trees$Select)     at
> io.baku.macrosy.Asserts$.assertImpl(Asserts.scala:13)   val result =
> Asserts.assert(cond, "abc")

Answer (score 5):

**The short answer** is easy, you can't make this work. `false` is a runtime value of `cond` in

```
val cond: Boolean = false
```

Compiler doesn't have access to it at compile time while expanding the macro.

You try to match `Literal` but the tree/`Expr` `cond` is not a literal.

So `Asserts.assert(false, "abc")` will work but `Asserts.assert(cond, "abc")` won't.

**The long answer** is that there are a couple of tricks.

***The first trick*** is that you can split your project into three subprojects *common*, *core*, *macros* and use `c.eval` instead of matching `Literal(Constant)` (if you put `cond` to *core* instead of *common*, this will not work):

*common*

```
object App {
  val cond: Boolean = false
}
```

*core* (depends on *macros* and *common*)

```
import App.cond

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Testing assert macro...")
    val result = Asserts.assert(cond, "abc") 
    //scalac: macro expansion has failed: Fix the code, whatever.
  }
}
```

*macros* (depends on *common*)

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

object Asserts {
  def assert(cond: Boolean, msg: String): Unit = macro assertImpl

  def assertImpl(c: blackbox.Context)(cond: c.Expr[Boolean], msg: c.Expr[String]) : c.Expr[Unit] = {
    import c.universe._
    val condEvaluated = c.eval(c.Expr[Boolean](c.untypecheck(cond.tree)))
    if (!condEvaluated) c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "Fix the code, whatever.") else c.Expr(q"()")
  }
}
```

[Scala: what can code in Context.eval reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56935330/scala-what-can-code-in-context-eval-reference/)

***The second trick*** is that if you keep `cond` in *core* then you can try to find definition tree of `cond` and get its right hand side:

*core* (depends on *macros*)

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Testing assert macro...")
    val cond: Boolean = false
    val result = Asserts.assert(cond, "abc")
    //scalac: macro expansion has failed: Fix the code, whatever.
  }
}
```

*macros*

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

object Asserts {    
  def assert(cond: Boolean, msg: String): Unit = macro assertImpl

  def assertImpl(c: blackbox.Context)(cond: c.Expr[Boolean], msg: c.Expr[String]) : c.Expr[Unit] = {
    import c.universe._

    var condValue: Option[Boolean] = None

    val traverser = new Traverser {
      override def traverse(tree: Tree): Unit = tree match {
        case q"$_ val cond: $_ = $expr" if tree.symbol == cond.tree.symbol => 
          expr match {
            case Literal(Constant(cond: Boolean)) =>
              condValue = Some(cond)
          }
        case _ => super.traverse(tree)
      }
    }

    c.enclosingRun.units.foreach(unit => traverser.traverse(unit.body))

    condValue.map(cond =>
      if (!cond) c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "Fix the code, whatever.") else c.Expr(q"()")
    ).getOrElse(
      c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "can't find cond")
    )
  }
}
```

[Creating a method definition tree from a method symbol and a body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767582/creating-a-method-definition-tree-from-a-method-symbol-and-a-body)

[Scala macro how to convert a MethodSymbol to DefDef with parameter default values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60806283/scala-macro-how-to-convert-a-methodsymbol-to-defdef-with-parameter-default-value)

[How to get the runtime value of parameter passed to a Scala macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59387459/how-to-get-the-runtime-value-of-parameter-passed-to-a-scala-macro)