# In scala, what is the easiest way to chain functions defined with a type class and of which output type depends on it?

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit

Assuming that a class `Thing` is defined, and an operation `+` is associated with a type class:

```
  trait TypeClass[X, Y] {

    type Out
    def v: Out
  }

  object TypeClass {

    implicit def summon[X <: Int, Y <: Int]: TypeClass[X, Y] = new TypeClass[X, Y] {

      type Out = Int

      override def v: Out = 2
    }
  }

  case class Thing[X]() {

    def +[Y](that: Thing[Y])(implicit typeClass: TypeClass[X, Y]): typeClass.Out = typeClass.v
  }
```

Now if I want to define a shortcut function `+2x`, which represents `X + Y + Y`. My first instinct was to introduce an implicit parameter:

```
    def ++[Y, Z](that: Thing[Y])(implicit t1: TypeClass[X, Y] { type Out <: Z }, t2: TypeClass[Z, Y]): t2.Out = t2.v
```

But then t2 becomes an impossible shoe to fill:

```
    assert(Thing(1) + Thing(2) == Thing(2)) // works fine

    assert(Thing(1) ++ Thing(2) == Thing(2)) // TypeClass.scala:34: could not find implicit value for parameter t2: TypeClass.this.TypeClass[Z,Int]
```

I could also use a more intuitive format:

```
    def +++[Y, Z](that: Thing[Y])(implicit t1: TypeClass[X, Y] { type Out <: Y }, a: Any = this + that + that): a.type =
      a
```

unfortunately implicit t1 cannot be made visible to the expression that defines the result:

```
TypeClass.scala:29: type mismatch;
 found   : a.type (with underlying type Any)
 required: AnyRef
```

so what is the easiest, most intuitive way to define this?

Thanks a lot for your opinion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lost type refinement. Replace

```
implicit def summon[X <: Int, Y <: Int]: TypeClass[X, Y] = new TypeClass[X, Y] {...
```

with

```
implicit def summon[X <: Int, Y <: Int]: TypeClass[X, Y] {type Out = Int} = new TypeClass[X, Y] {...
```

I guess `case class Thing[X]()` should be `case class Thing[X](x: X)`. Then

```
assert(Thing(1) + Thing(2) == 2) 
assert(Thing(1) ++ Thing(2) == 2)
```

work.

How to debug implicits: [In scala 2 or 3, is it possible to debug implicit resolution process in runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59348301/in-scala-2-or-3-is-it-possible-to-debug-implicit-resolution-process-in-runtime)