# Confusion about implicit example in scala

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit

```
implicit def list2ordered[A](x: List[A])(implicit elem2ordered: A => Ordered[A]): Ordered[List[A]] =
  new Ordered[List[A]] {
    //replace with a more useful implementation
    def compare(that: List[A]): Int = 1
}

println(List(1,2,3) <= List(4,5))
```

Can not understand how it work

Comment: Could you expand on what you don't understand ? is it the implicit parameter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List(1,2,3) <= List(4,5)
```

is desugared to

```
list2ordered(List(1, 2, 3))(Predef.intWrapper) <= List(4, 5)
```

The signature of `list2ordered`

```
implicit def list2ordered[A](x: List[A])(implicit elem2ordered: A => Ordered[A]): Ordered[List[A]]
```

means that it's a [conditional implicit conversion](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/chaining-implicits.html), namely, you have an implicit conversion `List[A] => Ordered[List[A]]` provided you have an implicit conversion `A => Ordered[A]`.

And `Predef.intWrapper` is precisely such an implicit conversion because it's `Int => RichInt` and `RichInt` extends `Ordered[Int]` (`RichInt <: ScalaNumberProxy[Int] <: OrderedProxy[Int] <: Ordered[Int]`).

You [can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59348301/in-scala-2-or-3-is-it-possible-to-debug-implicit-resolution-process-in-runtime) always see how implicits were resolved with `reify`

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
println(reify{List(1,2,3) <= List(4,5)}.tree)
//App.this.list2ordered(List.apply(1, 2, 3))(((x) => Predef.intWrapper(x))).$less$eq(List.apply(4, 5))
```