# Scala implicit class based on type class

Tags: scala, polymorphism, typeclass, implicit, value-class

```scala
implicit class IntIncrement(val underlying: Int) extends AnyVal {
    def increment(): Int = underlying + 1
}
```

This is valid and allows me to do something like `1.increment()`

I want to be able to constrain a type parameter to have this `.increment()` method on it, so I started doing this:

```scala
trait Increment[T] {
    def increment(value: T): T
}

object Increment {
    implicit val implInt: Increment[Int] = new Increment[Int] {
        def increment(value: Int): Int = {
            value + 1
        }
    }
}

def increment[T](value: T)(implicit valueIntDec: Increment[T]): T = {
    valueIntDec.increment(value)
}
```

issue is, this `increment` method only allows for `increment(1)` instead of `1.increment()`

is there any way to create an `implicit class` for any `T` that has an `implicit` of `Increment[T]`

```scala
implicit class ImplicitIncrement[T](val underlying: implicit Increment[T]) extends AnyVal {
    def increment(): T = increment(underlying)
}
```

something like this ^^

Comment: You're close. `(implicit val underlying: Increment[T])` should be instead of `(val underlying: implicit Increment[T])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that, just without `AnyVal`:

```
implicit class TIncrement[T : Increment](val underlying: T)  {
    def increment: T = implicitly[Increment[T]].increment(underlying)
}
```

But I am not sure I see the value in delegating to the type class here: rather than creating a type class implementation for every "incrementable" type, why not just have separate implicit classes that would just `increment` directly?

like

```
implicit class I(val v: Int) extends AnyVal { def increment = v + 1 }
implicit class L(val v: Long) extends AnyVal { def increment = v + 1 }
   // etc
```

**UPDATE**
Actually, you can do that *with* type class and `AnyVal` too:

```
implicit class TIncrement[T](val underlying: T) extends AnyVal  {
    def increment(implicit inc: Increment[T]): T = inc.increment(underlying)
}
```

Comment: *"why not just have separate implicit classes"* I guess having a type class, its instances and the only implicit class defining a syntax via delegation to the type class (rather than having separate implicit classes/implicit conversions) is a common pattern. For example if you'd like to define an instance for `List[A]` having an instance for `A`, with a type class this would be easy e.g. `implicit def listInc[A: Increment]: Increment[List[A]] = new Increment[List[A]] { override def increment(value: List[A]): List[A] = value.map(_.increment()) }`.

Comment: But with implicit classes this would be harder: `implicit class Lst[A](val v: List[A])(implicit ev: A => /*A*/ {def increment(): A})...` seems not to work.

Comment: @DmytroMitin though, I am still not sure what is the problem with 
`implicit class X[A](val x: List[A]) { def increment(implicit _: TIncrement[A]) = x.map(x.increment) } `

Comment: I guess `(implicit _: TIncrement[A])` can't be correct. With implicit class you don't define an implicit instance of type `TIncrement[A]`, you define an implicit conversion `A => TIncrement[A]`.

Comment: Yeah, I see your point now.

Comment: Although what you proposed with implicit conversions/implicit classes was close to a pattern different from type class, namely magnet https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/sxUpSmC7S8KUXJiEaXCWXA/1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74203834/group-typeclass-instances-by-type-parameter